# How to see crashes/exceptions in real-time report in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have sent an exception on the client:

```js
gtag('event', 'exception', {
  description,
});
```

But looks like only non exception events are visible in real-time report.

My question:

- Is there a way to enable it?
- Can I build a custom real-time report?
- Or do I have to work around it with a different event category? EG:

```js
gtag('event', 'error', {
  description,
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue. They advertise how to create exception: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/exceptions but there is no way to display them in the Google Analytics, so really, I don't see the point of those exception events.